# Redirect to SharePoint online login

Tags: sharepoint, asp.net-web-api, odata, office365

I have a SharePoint provider hosted app deployed on Azure, with ASP.NET MVC. Because we chose to use AngularJS, we have added ASP.NET Web API controllers as well. We have managed to create the SharePoint client context in the API controllers by sharing the token information from the MVC controllers via cookies (the API controllers actions have a SharePointApiContextFilter just as the MVC controllers have the SharePointContextFilter to handle the SharePoint client context creation).

I have added an OData controller for reporting purposes, which will export data to Excel (via Excel's OData Data Feed import). I would like to make this controller to authenticate against SharePoint online. Excel has already implemented this functionality, since I have tried to import data from a SharePoint library via REST.

Using Fiddler, I have noticed the SharePoint online returns a 401 response with a authentication challenge (WWW-Authenticate) header:

> WWW-Authenticate: IDCRL Type="BPOSIDCRL",
>   EndPoint="/sites/Test/_vti_bin/idcrl.svc/",
>   RootDomain="sharepoint.com", Policy="MBI"

This is the full response:

> HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
>   Content-Length: 0 Content-Type: application/xml;charset=utf-8 Expires:
>   Tue, 07 Jul 2015 07:34:08 GMT Last-Modified: Wed, 22 Jul 2015 07:34:08
>   GMT Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5 X-SharePointHealthScore: 0
>   X-MSDAVEXT_Error: 917656;
>   Access+denied.+Before+opening+files+in+this+location%2c+you+must+first+browse+to+the+web+site+and+select+the+option+to+login+automatically.
>   DATASERVICEVERSION: 3.0 X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319 SPRequestGuid:
>   be6d1c9d-806b-2000-20ed-4d42443d8365 request-id:
>   be6d1c9d-806b-2000-20ed-4d42443d8365 X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
>   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 16.0.0.4121
>   X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly
>   P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo
>   OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI" WWW-Authenticate: IDCRL
>   Type="BPOSIDCRL", EndPoint="/sites/Test/_vti_bin/idcrl.svc/",
>   RootDomain="sharepoint.com", Policy="MBI" Date: Wed, 22 Jul 2015
>   07:34:08 GMT

Can somebody tell me how to construct this type of response in the OData controller (maybe via a custom action filter)?